# Create a lookup table with Doctrine2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have recently installed Doctrine2 on my web server and all works great. I have setup all my entities but now I'm at the point where I want to create a lookup table and I'm a bit confused how to do that. I want a table which looks like this:

```
tbl_Role                       tbl_User
+--------+----------+          +--------+----------+--------------+----------+
|   id   |   Name   |          |   id   |   Name   |   Password   |   Role   |
+--------+----------+          +--------+----------+--------------+----------+
|   1    |   Admin  |
|   2    |   User   |
|   3    |   Free   |
+--------+----------+
```

Between the `Role` and the `User` table consists a OneToMany relation (one `Role` has many `Users`) and this table does not change in future. I do not want to use Enums because of the update or reorder problem with them (if nevertheless something changed)

My question now is how I can represent this lookup table as a Doctrine entity? Normally if I want to create a new `User` I have to get the fitting `Role` from the DB and set it as a reference in the `User` entity. This seems a bit expensive to me. It would be great if I could have only the `Role` IDs in static PHP fields so I can set them as reference for the `User`. Is this possible?

Another problem is how I get the lookup values into the database. Can I implement a method into the `Role` entity itself which is executed after the `Role` table is created? This way it would be possible to mark the constructor as private and all values are present after a migration.

Comment: Are you aware of Doctrine references? https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.2/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php#L374-413.  Given the actual database id of a role, getting a doctrine reference is inexpensive.  I would still be tempted to just store role as a string and not have a Doctrine 2 relation at all.  You can still make a table of roles for other software if you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it won't be too expensive, because [Doctrine2 has a few cache layers](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/caching.html#integrating-with-the-orm) and these queries will be efficiently cached since the `Role` table won't change.

Anyway, if `Role` table won't change, I'm not sure if it should be kept in database. You could create a "static" factory service for it to create simple value objects as a part of your domain layer.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean but I would like to have this table in the database. It's a very important relation and if you only look into the database (without the factory) you have no references to the integeres if this table is not available. It's a design concept and I reluctantly would like to break it.

Comment: Well, you should design your software, not database. DB is just an I/O. Anyway, as mentioned in answer, it should not be a problem because of Doctrine's caching layer.